# Reading in a very large file

Tags: cocoa

I'm working on an application that reads in a huge text file (can be up to 5gb in size).  Currently, I am using fscanf to read in the file, because I have found it to be the fastest so far.  However, it still takes quite a large quantity of time to read the whole file in.

Is there a faster way to read in data from a file?

Comment: You probably want to use `mmap`: http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap

Answer (score 2):

First, you should strongly avoid reading a 5GB file into memory as a single step. The memory impact alone should keep you away from this approach. Instead, you should try to take another approach such as:

- Process the data as you read it and throw away the data
- Convert the file to a Core Data model prior to work
- Convert the file to a fixed-length record format so you can do random-access
- Modify the file format so that it is less redundant
- Index the file so you can do random-access
- Partition the data into separate files
- Memory map the file using `NSFileWrapper` (far from a panacea, but can be useful in conjunction with the above; `NSFileWrapper` automatically does memory mapping)

You should start by getting a performance baseline:

```
time cat thebigfile.dat > /dev/null
```

It is hard to imagine reading the file much faster than that, so that's your floor.

You should definitely do some performance analysis in Instruments and make sure the problem is the reading and not the processing. In particular, memory allocation can be more expensive than you may expect, particularly in a multi-threaded app.

Once you've investigated the above, and you still need really fast management of on-disk data, look at [dispatch_io](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) and [dispatch_data](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-10-14-whats-new-in-gcd.html). This is a really awesome tool for high-speed data management. But it is almost always better to improve your basic algorithms first before worrying about this kind of optimization.

Comment: I guess my biggest problem is the processing, and not the reading in part, since I currently have it set up to read in line by line.  So I guess I should rephrase my question.  Is there any way to process the data faster?  Like if I have 1 million lines, each of them have the same attributes (Name, date, etc)...and I want to store each line in an array.  Is there any faster way then just doing object.name = ... and then [ObjectArray addObject: object]?

Comment: What does Instruments say? Where are your hotspots? Don't even begin to start optimizing until you've spent some time in Instruments and have a sense of what's going on.